# Why google finds a page excluded by robots.txt?

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt, web-crawler

i'm using robots.txt to exclude some pages from spiders.

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /track.php
```

When i search something refeered to this page, google says: "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

It means that the robots.txt is working.. but why the link to the page is still found by the spider? I'd like to have no link to the 'track.php' page... how i should setup the robots.txt? (or something like .htaccess and so on..?)

Comment: If you access `domain.com/robots.txt` do you then see your robots.txt or a 404 page?

Comment: i see the robots.txt!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what happened:

- Googlebot saw, on some other page, a link to track.php. Let's call that page "source.html".
- Googlebot tried to visit your track.php file.
- Your robots.txt told Googlebot not to read the file.

So Google knows that source.html links to track.php, but it doesn't know what track.php contains. You didn't tell Google not to index track.php; you told Googlebot not to read and index the data *inside* track.php.

As [Google's documentation says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en):

> While Google won't crawl or index the content of pages blocked by robots.txt, we may still index the URLs if we find them on other pages on the web. As a result, the URL of the page and, potentially, other publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the site, or the title from the Open Directory Project (www.dmoz.org), can appear in Google search results.

There's not a lot you can do about this. For your own pages, you can use the `x-robots-tag` or `noindex meta tag` as described in that documentation. That will prevent Googlebot from indexing the URL if it finds a link in your pages. But if some page that you don't control links to that track.php file, then Google is quite likely to index it.

Comment: Nice explaination, i've just read about that.. i'll try with noindex!  (hoping no one is linking that page). Thanks

Comment: i see that "noindex" could be used only with a meta-tag and so it will exclude from index all links in that page. I'll try to use <a href="track.php" rel="nofollow" /> .. will it work?

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi: "will it work?" I don't know. Google's documentation is unclear on that. I suggest you change your page and then [request that Google remove the link from their index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164734?rd=1).